# How can I get an Arduino Uno run the Feather9x_RX example?

Tags: arduino-uno, rf

How do I get this [example](https://github.com/adafruit/RadioHead/blob/master/examples/feather/Feather9x_RX/Feather9x_RX.ino) to run on using an Arduino Uno. I've updated `RFM95_RST`, `RFM95_CS` & `RFM95_INT` to the relevant pins (2,4 & 3 respectively).

This is the output on the Serial Monitor when the sketch is loaded:

```
Feather LoRa RX Test!
ERROR: Failed to put device in LoRa mode.
RH_RF95_REG_01_OP_MODE: 0
LoRa radio init failed
```

I've followed [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-rfm69hcw-and-rfm96-rfm95-rfm98-lora-packet-padio-breakouts/arduino-wiring) wiring set up:
[image]

[image]

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>

#define RFM95_RST     2
#define RFM95_CS      4
#define RFM95_INT     3

// Change to 434.0 or other frequency, must match RX's freq!
#define RF95_FREQ 915.0

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);

// Blinky on receipt
#define LED 13

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RFM95_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(1);
  }
  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Feather LoRa RX Test!");

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);

  while (!rf95.init()) {
    Serial.println("LoRa radio init failed");
    Serial.println("Uncomment '#define SERIAL_DEBUG' in RH_RF95.cpp for detailed debug info");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("LoRa radio init OK!");

  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb250Fd250, +13dbM
  if (!rf95.setFrequency(RF95_FREQ)) {
    Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.print("Set Freq to: "); Serial.println(RF95_FREQ);

  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, 13dBm, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on

  // The default transmitter power is 13dBm, using PA_BOOST.
  // If you are using RFM95/96/97/98 modules which uses the PA_BOOST transmitter pin, then
  // you can set transmitter powers from 5 to 23 dBm:
  rf95.setTxPower(23, false);
}

void loop()
{
  if (rf95.available())
  {
    // Should be a message for us now
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len))
    {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      RH_RF95::printBuffer("Received: ", buf, len);
      Serial.print("Got: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
       Serial.print("RSSI: ");
      Serial.println(rf95.lastRssi(), DEC);

      // Send a reply
      uint8_t data[] = "And hello back to you";
      rf95.send(data, sizeof(data));
      rf95.waitPacketSent();
      Serial.println("Sent a reply");
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Receive failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: look at your `while (!rf95.init())` code closely ... what happens if the radio is not ready when that code is executed?

Comment: so it gets stuck. I've replaced `while(1);` with `delay(1000);`  but now it just repeats the same error haha. I kind of thought the example would work out of the box, providing the wiring was ok.

Comment: Scrap that, i was looking at a different example. Your suggestion seems to have work! Thanks

Comment: Newbie here. I'm also getting same error after connecting RFM9x LoRa module with Arduino. What did you do to address this error? I can't seem to understand the suggested way in while (!rf95.init()) part of the code. Thanks in advance...